# Wget ftp and skip existing files

Tags: bash, ftp, wget

I would like to use a bash script running on my RPI, that:

Checks to see if local and remote are synchronized. Downloads anything new from every directory and put it in a appropriate local folder. Local directories are already created.

I've got the upload to work, but the download I'm not sure. Can anyone please try to edit?

```
HOST='IP-ADDRESS'

USER='USERNAME'

PASSWD='PASSWORD'

LOCAL_FILES='/media/A/'

wget ftp://$HOST/A/ * -nc --ftp-user=$USER --ftp-password=$PASSWD --no-passive-ftp

wput --disable-tls --basename=$LOCAL_FILES/ $LOCAL_FILES/* ftp://$USER:$PASSWD@$HOST/A/
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check rsync - might be what you want

Comment: Would that still be possible if the FTP-server is running Windows?

Comment: Have you tried the `--mirror` option of wget?

Comment: No I haven't tried that. But sounds promising.